# For ALB - is there an equivalent of fail2ban?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer, fail2ban

ALB (Application Load Balancing) is a layer 7 load balancer on AWS ELB.

For ALB - is there an equivalent of fail2ban which can prevent DDoS attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/)? Not part of ALB per se, but may meet the goal.

Comment: Specifically, you may want to check out rate-based rules, a feature of AWS WAF. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/how-aws-waf-works.html